# Несколько OnClick вызывают одно и то же Activity. Можно ли изменять содержимое Activity в зависимости от использованного OnClick?

Tags: java, android, activity

У меня есть ListActivity. При нажатии на любой из элементов списка должно открываться новое Activity с описанием выбранного элемента (TextView). И вот открывающееся Activity я хочу одно, а описание чтоб менялось в зависимости от нажатого элемента.

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается? Определить по какому элементу нажали или передать эту информацию с другое активити?

Comment: Да, можно. Для более качественного ответа потрудитесь оформить краткий, завершенный и достоверный вопрос (смотрите справку по ресурсу)

Comment: Я вроде понял, что вы хотите, но для получения ответа вам придется показать код вашего `OnCLick`

Comment: Спасибо, ЮрийСПб, за фразу "передать эту информацию в другое активити". Это всё объясняет.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Позиция нажатого элемента ListView и её получение в запущенном активити](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420555/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-listview)